# Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert: unrecognized_name

Tags: java, web-services, rest, ssl

I am new to REST, I have recently developed a small java REST Client to consume an api over SSL (https) using jersey. However, I am challenged with the error below :

Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert:  unrecognized_name
........
........
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert: unrecognized_name

I read from some posts about disabling SNI in java but I am not clear.
Since I am using eclispe IDE, I appended  " -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false" to my eclipse.ini file BUT the error still appears. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: I was using `System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");` but that no longer works for the handshake exception on `java version "1.7.0_79" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6) (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1)`.

Comment: @PLA, thanks. I am using java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b18). I am NOT sure of the best solution, been googling  around for the past 24 hours!

Comment: `-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false` will probably have no effect when placed in `eclipse.ini`. If you're running your application from within Eclipse, this parameter should be in the application's run configuration options.

Comment: Have you checked that the host name you're trying to connect to matches the host name in the server certificate (the one as expected by the server)?

Comment: @Bruno I do not use certificates yet. thanks

Comment: @SyCode Are you using anonymous cipher suites then?

Comment: @Bruno I didn't use that. Not sure what it does. Could you explain, maybe I could apply it later.

Comment: @SyCode There's a set of insecure cipher suites that work without server certificate (anonymous cipher suites). They're disabled by default (being insecure). If you haven't enabled them explicitly, you're using a certificate. You might have not set up a meaningful one (one issued by a known CA, or a test certificate valid in your environment), but you'd be using a cert. (Not knowing what name the server is expecting or what's configured on the server you're connecting to would certainly be part of the cause of the problems you're encountering in this question.)

Comment: @Bruno many thanks for this handful information. I would investigate my environment and make proper adjustments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised there was a need to handle the exception( "javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert: unrecognized_name") by using setting the security context to "TLSv1" and employing TrustManager and HostnameVerifier (see snippet below). This solved the issue for me.

```
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
        System.setProperty("https.protocols","TLSv1");

        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = {new InsecureTrustManager()};
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new InsecureHostnameVerifier();
```

Comment: Do you *really* want to use an insecure trust manager and hostname verifier?

Comment: @Bruno , since this isn't in a production environment, the current approach suffices.

Comment: Up to you... The problem with that sort of workarounds is that they often end up unnoticed in production code. (It's easy to forget to re-instate proper validation, especially if you're close to a deadline and don't have time to figure out to do things securely.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure Your CA certs file contains the certificate you are connecting to.
2. Download and install the JCE for java 1.8 (http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jce/8/jce_policy-8.zip)
3. Remove the -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false

Comment: Link is broken, below is the updated link;
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html